# Java sorting a collection of datetime values

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I'm pulling the date and time of emails using the notes.jar lotus notes api. When I add them to a collection, if add them like this:

```
Vector times = doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("PostedDate");
    for (int j=0; j<times.size(); j++) {
      Object time = times.elementAt(j);
      if (time.getClass().getName().endsWith("DateTime")) {
          String Listadd = ((DateTime)time).getLocalTime();
          NotesDates.add((DateTime)time);
```

I get the error:

```
lotus.domino.local.DateTime cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

When I add the values as String the code runs, but I cannot sort the collection.

How can I sort the collection of dates and times to find the earliest and latest?

Comment: You need to write a `Comparator<DateTime>`

Comment: `Vector` and Lotus Notes, haven't see those in a long while..

Comment: Just wondering: why `time.getClass().getName().endsWith("DateTime")` instead of just `time instanceof DateTime`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options. Here are two.

1. Use a collection of java.util.Date instead of lotus.domino.local.DateTime
   The lotus notes DateTime object has a method `toJavaDate()`, and a java.util.Date implements the Comparable interface for you
2. Implement a custom comparator for lotus.domino.local.DateTime object. It would probably be easiest to convert the date to a java date again, and use it's compare method, instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom `Comparator` that take as input the `DateTime` of Lotus.

Inside the code compare the `DateTime` as you need, for example converting them to a standard `java.util.Date` or getting single elements (year, month, date...) and comparing them singularly.